# Is possible to deploy a self contained .NET Framework application?

Tags: c#, .net, self-contained

I'm developing a C#.Net application that uses the .Net Framework but I'm having trouble when users are installing the application on their computers. Some of them just don't know how to install the .Net Framework.

I'm searching for a solution to this problem and I found the self contained deployment use in .Net Core applications.

The problem is that my application doesn't use .Net Core, it is a WPF application.

I already search the web and all solutions I find brings me to the .Net Core self contained deployment.

What can be done in order to deploy a "self contained" .Net Framework application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are they installing to? What version?

Comment: Have you heard of ClickOnce deployment? Is pretty awesome and is typically what i use to deploy to a share drive and have all my users install app and updates.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland The target OS is Windows x86. I need the application to run in all the windows versions from XP to 10.

Comment: @Miguel Yes I have searched for that, but turns out ClickOnce is incompatible with applications that requires to run with Admin privilegies (which is the case of my application).

Comment: Ah, XP. I was wondering what Windows OS doesn't have .NET framework 4+ installed.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Yep. However lets say I want to dump XP users and work only with win7+. If I build my application with the .Net Framework 4.0 it will work on every single machine with no need to install any .net dependencies?

Comment: @underthevoid Good point. Win7 comes with .NET 3.5.1 which is has WPF.

Comment: If you don't mind spending money, applications such as [ThinApp](https://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp.html) can wrap your executable with all its dependencies into a single exe file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use WiX to create a "bootstrap" installer, which will install required frameworks before installing your application.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html

Comment: It's what I used to do back when I needed to support a WPF app on XP/Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Find a version of the .NET Framework that all  of your target computers already have, and set Visual Studio to target that version of the framework.

Then, just copy/paste all of the files out of the bin/release folder into a folder on the target computer and run your program's executable.

If all of your target computers have Windows 10, you can deploy using version 4.6 of the framework, and be guaranteed that your clients already have it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight however the windows targets range from windows XP to windows 10. Do you know upfront a possible .Net Framework compatible with all these windows versions?

Comment: To go back that far, you have to go all the way back to .NET 3.5.  Microsoft doesn't support Windows XP anymore; it's incredibly insecure, you can no longer get updates for it, and I strongly discourage you from developing against it.  The earliest version of Windows I would contemplate nowadays is Version 7, and Microsoft support for it ends in a couple of years.

Comment: Hmm I think I'll accept your suggestion and ignore XP users. If I'm going to work with win7+ do you know which would be the highest framework version I could use?

Comment: Windows 7 supports the latest version of the framework; though it doesn't come with Windows 7 out of the box, there's a good chance it's already there if your users are reasonably good about updates.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Suggesting a rollback to the previous version is not a solution.

Comment: @t3chb0t: Not all versions of Windows support all versions of .NET.  If you read the comments above, you'll see that the OP needed to support Windows versions all the way back to Windows XP.

Comment: Not by default but what are runtimes for?